# type as returntype in c++

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a possibility to return a type as a returntype from a function
and use it for a member variable using something like this:

```
constexpr type myFunction(int a, int b){
     if(a + b == 8) return int_8t;
     if(a + b == 16) return int_16t;
     if(a + b == 32) return int_32t;
     return int_64t;
}

template<int x, int y>
class test{
    using type = typename myFunction(x, y);
    private:
    type m_variable;
};
```

When trying this example in Qt it says

```
Error: 'constexpr' does not name a type
Error: 'test' is not a template type
class test{
      ^
```

In an earlier question someone showed me http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional this function, but it works only for 2 Types.

Comment: Types must be resolved at compile-time, so `a` and `b` will have to be template parameters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24466621/701092

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do this with a normal function.  However, it is easily done using template meta-programming.  This kind of template is sometimes called a *type function*.

```
#include <cstdint>

template<int bits> struct integer { /* empty */ };

// Specialize for the bit widths we want.
template<> struct integer<8>  { typedef int8_t  type; };
template<> struct integer<16> { typedef int16_t type; };
template<> struct integer<32> { typedef int32_t type; };
```

It can be used like this.

```
using integer_type = integer<16>::type;
integer_type number = 42;
```

Remember to precede `integer<T>::type` with the `typename` keyword if `T` is itself a template parameter.

I leave it as an exercise to you to extend this to a template that accepts two integers as parameters and returns the appropriate type based on the sum of the two.