# 'using type' in C++ causes several errors

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++14

In my question [type as returntype in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327066/type-as-returntype-in-c) I was provided with an answer that 
gave me such a structure:

```
template <int N>
struct int_type {
    using type = std::conditional_t<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
                 std::conditional_t<N <= 16, std::uint16_t,
                 std::conditional_t<N <= 32, std::uint32_t,
                 std::conditional_t<N <= 64, std::uint64_t,
                 std::uintmax_t>>>>;
};
```

That seemed to do excactly what I need, how ever the practice looks different, since I can't compile it because of the following errors:

```
...Error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'type'
 using type = std::conditional_t<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
       ^
...Error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
...Error: expected ';' before '=' token
 using type = std::conditional_t<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
            ^
...Error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

I tried to google it, but none of the posts I found seem to adress this specific problems. Can anyone explain me what is wrong with this code? I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: `conditional_t` is a helper type introduced in C++14. Are you compiling with `-std=c++14` flag?

Comment: @PeterT that's the thing, `std::conditional_t` is a typedef for the `conditional::type` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Comment: @vsoftco my bad, I should've  read it more carefully

Comment: clearly, the error indicates you didn't even enable C++11, not to mention C++14 required for `std::conditional_t`. It expects *using-declaration* syntax, hence the error where compiler wants *nested name specifier* after `using`

Comment: I added CONFIG += c++14 but still got the same errors.

Comment: @TreeOfLife what compiler? and shouldn't you add `CONFIG+=-std=c++14` ?

Comment: I just googled, aparently c++14 features aren't all supported with my version of MinGW (4.8)...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127217/how-can-i-use-c14-features-when-building-qmake-projects

Comment: @TreeOfLife try [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecf9c9d28c00b981) instead

Comment: This gives me another error,  'uint8_t' is not a member of 'std'
     using type = typename std::conditional<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
                                                    ^

Comment: @TreeOfLife did you include `<cstdint>` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Oh, I used stdint.h, what is the difference there?

Comment: @TreeOfLife `stdint.h` might not define those typedefs in `std` namespace

Comment: @PiotrS. can you add your code and what you explained put into an answer, so that I can mark it? That all together fixed the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly legal as long as your compiler supports [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) stdlib's `<type_traits>` that define an alias template for `std::conditional` trait.

However, the error message clearly indicates you've not even enabled [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), therefore `using` is not parsed as an alias at all. To do that, add `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` option to your configuration.

If you can't, then in [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) you can easily implement your own `conditional` trait:

```
template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
struct conditional
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct conditional<false, T, F>
{
    typedef F type;
};

template <int N>
struct int_type {
    typedef typename conditional<N <= 8, uint8_t,
                 typename conditional<N <= 16, uint16_t,
                 typename conditional<N <= 32, uint32_t,
                 typename conditional<N <= 64, uint64_t,
                 uintmax_t>::type>::type>::type>::type type;
};
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can use `std::conditional` instead of `std::conditional_t`, the only difference is that you need to access a nested typedef `type` on your own, which is a *dependent name* (`typename` keyword needed in front of a *nested name specifier*):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <int N>
struct int_type {
    using type = typename std::conditional<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
                 typename std::conditional<N <= 16, std::uint16_t,
                 typename std::conditional<N <= 32, std::uint32_t,
                 typename std::conditional<N <= 64, std::uint64_t,
                 std::uintmax_t>::type>::type>::type>::type;
};
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), you need to include `<cstdint>` instead of `<stdint.h>`. The former guarantees the names are defined in the `std` namespace (the latter may define them only in the *global* namespace).

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer here for the sake of completeness.

You need to `#include <cstdint>` and `#include <type_traits>`, then compile with C++14 support. Code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct int_type {
    using type = std::conditional_t<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
                 std::conditional_t<N <= 16, std::uint16_t,
                 std::conditional_t<N <= 32, std::uint32_t,
                 std::conditional_t<N <= 64, std::uint64_t,
                 std::uintmax_t>>>>;
};

int main()
{
    int_type<10>::type t; // std::uint16_t
    t = 12;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9352f3349f48bff4

Answer (score -1):

Huh, when you do a typedef the compiler tells you what's wrong. Those are dependant typenames so you need a "typename" in front of it. so this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <int N>
struct int_type {
    using mytype = typename std::conditional<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
                     typename std::conditional<N <= 16, std::uint16_t,
                       typename std::conditional<N <= 32, std::uint32_t,
                         typename std::conditional<N <= 64, std::uint64_t,
                           std::uintmax_t
                         >::type
                       >::type
                     >::type
                   >::type;
};
```

Comment: `std::conditional_t` is not a typedef, but an alias template, it adds `typename` on its own in the definition

Comment: @PiotrS. I mean that I wrote `typedef std::conditional<...> type;` and it showed a different error

Comment: remove the first part of your answer then, nonetheless, the error doesn't indicate compiler's inability to resolve a dependent name, rather, missing support for aliasing

Comment: @vsoftco I'm pretty sure they are dependent types, which is why the  `conditional_t` alias uses `using conditional_t = typename conditional<B,T,F>::type;`. You are correct that this is not the reason why OPs compilation failed and it's not really relevant to his question but those are dependent types.

Comment: @PeterT ok, you are right, they are dependent, removed my comment, what I meant is that they belong to the current instantiation and do not need the `typename` qualifier, as the compiler is not confused between a type and an eventual variable declaration. See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name near the bottom, where some examples are given about the usage of `typename`.